# Every shutdown: Stopped (with error) /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-nvme0n1p4_crypt

Tags: shutdown, 17.04, systemd

I'm on 17.04 and every time I shut down I see this error flash up.

cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
UUID=5d47eab8-0ece-441c-80bd-983de1bcbf55 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime                           0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=5A37-2794                            /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077                                          0 1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw                                                  0 0
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p4_crypt               /crypt          ext4    defaults,noatime                                    0 2
/crypt/home                               /home           none    defaults,bind                                       0 0
/crypt/mysql                              /var/lib/mysql  none    defaults,bind                                       0 0
```

cat /etc/crypttab

```
# <target name> <source device>     <key file>  <options>
nvme0n1p4_crypt UUID=9c0da76e-727a-40f2-8050-20d2a9ab97ae none luks,discard
```

journalctl -b -1 -x shows the error:

```
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko dbus[1086]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko NetworkManager[1096]: <info>  [1506025632.7451] exiting (success)
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko wpa_supplicant[1392]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko systemd[1]: Stopped (with error) /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-nvme0n1p4_crypt.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2dname\x2dnvme0n1p4_crypt.device has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2dname\x2dnvme0n1p4_crypt.device has finished shutting down.
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko systemd[1]: Stopped (with error) /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-0.
-- Subject: Unit sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d0.device has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d0.device has finished shutting down.
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko systemd[1]: Stopped (with error) /dev/dm-0.
-- Subject: Unit dev-dm\x2d0.device has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-dm\x2d0.device has finished shutting down.
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko systemd[1]: Stopped WPA supplicant.
-- Subject: Unit wpa_supplicant.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit wpa_supplicant.service has finished shutting down.
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko systemd[1]: Stopped (with error) /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS1-9c0da76e727a40f2805020d2a9ab97ae-nvme0n1p4_crypt.
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko systemd[1]: Stopped (with error) /dev/disk/by-uuid/77a337c5-60a1-4fd3-a94c-3c20eab278ac.
Sep 21 21:27:12 meowko dbus[1086]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service': Refusing activation, D-Bus is shutting down.
```

uname -a

```
 Linux meowko 4.10.0-35-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP
 Wed Sep 13 07:46:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Relevant(?) `lshw` output

```
description: Non-Volatile memory controller
product: NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951
vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
version: 01
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
resources: irq:16 memory:de400000-de403fff ioport:c000(size=256)
```

**Anyone got ideas of how to fix this, if it does need fixing?**

Comment: `UUID =`? (crypttab)

Comment: @TomYan you mean that space? No, that's just a copy and paste error, sorry! The space isn't there in my crypttab.